# handle exception into alert box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I coerce an exception message that has bubbled from my business layer into an alert box in javascript?

BTW, I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

Thanks,
Rod.

Comment: Are you making the request via ajax?

Comment: Is the exception occurring in the rendering of the view or in the controller action?

Comment: In the controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom action filter attribute and apply it to the action method.
In the override version of OnActionExecuted() you'll have to set the filterContext.Result to some  RedirectResult/RedirectRouteResult in order to return anything to the browser as the exception has set it to EmptyResult. So redirect to some error page or controller action which renders html with the javascript for the alert :)  Here's the custom ActionFilter Attribute you could start with:

```
public class ExceptionAlerterFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(null!= filterContext.Exception && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {

            RedirectResult result = new RedirectResult(some_url_you_need_to_set);
            filterContext.Result = result;
            //yes, you have to set the ExceptionHandled to stop the error bubbling
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Gets a bit messy, but I hope answers your question ?